# Android finishAndRemoveTask dosenot start second activity

Tags: android

Android finishAndRemoveTask dosenot start second activity

this is the first activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentAct.this, secondAct.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("abcd", j);
                startActivity(i);

               finishAndRemoveTask();
```

If I dont add `finishAndRemoveTask();` it works fine the `secondAct starts`

this is the manifest

```
       <activity
        android:name="currentAct"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"
        android:taskAffinity=".ShortCutActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="secondAct"
        android:noHistory="true"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:taskAffinity=".ShortCutActivity">
```

ShortCutActivity is just a `mainactivity`

how can we start second activity and remove the first activity from stack also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this before calling startActivity(intent)

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` for launching intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Referring to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK):

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.